# What does テンションが異次元 mean?

Tags: translation

Español:

¿Qué quiere decir テンションが異次元?

*Google translate* lo traduce como **"La tensión es una dimensión diferente"** Pero yo no entiendo muy bien esa traducción ¿La traducción está mal? ¿O es una expresión? Y si es una expresión ¿Qué quiere decir?

---

English:

What does テンションが異次元 mean?

*Google translate* translates this as **"the tension is a different dimension"** But I don't really get this translation. Is it a bad translation? Or is it an expression? And if it's an expression, what does it mean?

---

<sub>*Originally asked in Spanish.*</sub>

Comment: Donde has visto esta expresion?

Comment: Es posible estar a dar sua traducion del テンションが異次元? plus essa google translate y cualquier context. Si entiende ingles, consequir a escribir essa pergunta en ingles ou japonais? Disculupe para mi espanol peior.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because only questions in Japanese or English are allowed, unless a translation into either of these is provided.

Comment: es que mientras la palabra テンション sí parece poder traducirse como "tensión" por su pronunciación, la verdad es que es una expresión "japanglish" que tiene otra significado. Yo que tú lo buscaría en un diccionario ingles-japones y traducirlo al español si no sabes ingles

Answer (score 4):

Sorry that I don't speak Spanish.

It involves two colloquial words that may make it difficult to interpret.

- テンション

  As pointed out in a comment, it never actually means what English *tension* does. We already have an answer here: [Meaning of 変なテンション](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28352/7810), which says "(a level of) excitement or hyperness". Or generally the feeling that drives you active.
- 次元

  It is scientifically "dimension", but in spoken language "the range where something can be compared on the same basis". So 次元が違う is often used like English "on another level" or "in a different ballpark". 異次元 is a single word that means the same with 違う次元.

As a whole, テンションが異次元 means something like "(my) excitement goes beyond the normal level/bound", which is an exaggerated way to tell that someone is super-frantic. This expression is not textbook-like, but is something you can quite much expect to hear.

Answer (score 0):

テンション = Tension in the air

異次元 = On a different level

That's the straightforward translation of the two words. Not sure how well those idiomatic expression would translate into a different language though.

-- Starfox