# How is テンション used in Japanese?

Tags: words

When I looked it up in my dictionary, all I got was 'tension,' when I have first hand knowledge that this definition RARELY is used with this word, in Japanese. Commonly, I see it in テンションが上がる, to express someone is pumped for something, but are there other uses for this word, in the language, that I may not be aware of?

Comment: 和製英語っぽく.......?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of 変なテンション](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28352/meaning-of-%e5%a4%89%e3%81%aa%e3%83%86%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3)

Answer (score 2):

Mostly it's used to describe a mood or atmosphere of excitement or being pumped up as you said.

In a work context it could also describe a atmosphere of intensity and collective focus, such as when a team nears a deadline.

The latter usage sometimes approaches the English meaning of stress and pressure.

Comment: Hmm. Could you give me a couple examples of its use in the first context, outside of テンションが上がる?

Comment: I've heard the opposite, テンションが下がった (i.e. the tension went down)
This usually has a negative connotation, like excitement being deflated for some reason. For example the family was super-excited about a picnic, but then heard it's going to rain that day.